# Javascript-added datalist and text input not showing options

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, datalist

I was trying to make a search bar for a navigation menu with data lists, and I used JavaScript to do it automatically on every page. However, it is not working, how do I solve this?

Definition of the text input

```js
let searchBar = document.createElement("input");
searchBar.type = "text";
searchBar.list = "search-results";
searchBar.id = "search-bar";
searchBar.name = "search-bar";
```

The datalist

```js
let searchResults = document.createElement("datalist");
searchResults.id = "search-results";
```

And the options

```js
const searchPagesDisplayNames = ["Home","Numbers","WIPs","Interpreters","Noise","What's the difference?","Star Calculator", "Tsevhu","Bee Swarm Ideas"];
const searchLinks = []; //Censored (not a mistake)
for (let i = 0; i < searchPagesDisplayNames.length; i++) {
  let option = document.createElement("option");
  option.value = searchPagesDisplayNames[i];
  searchResults.appendChild(option);
}
```

The search bar and the data list are being added to the same parent element later on. I've looked through the code and found nothing wrong. Please help

Comment: Can you add a bit of html context? Will be easier to debug.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @SimonLeroux There is none because it's all being added by the javascript. I can give you the entire script, though